# speeding up Gaussian elimination php code for big data

Tags: php, gaussian

I am working on php / mysql project , I need to solve a large linear equations and variables (+20000) 
I am new to php and I am using this code so far

more info on how the code work  : [click here](https://martin-thoma.com/solving-linear-equations-with-gaussian-elimination/)

the problem is it takes very long time for execution (5 minuets for 500 variables)

is there any thing I can do to speed up the process? 
is there any alternative php code that can do the job faster?

I am currently work on wampserver php 5.6.35

thank you

Comment: sorry I couldn't post the code here, I don't know why!

Comment: I would highly recommend to upgrade to a newer PHP version (7.2 or higher). PHP 7.* is a lot faster than PHP 5.*. Also PHP 5.* is no longer supported.

Comment: thank you D B! , I upgraded to 7.4 , it works much faster now

Comment: still slow for big number of variables